# React Component not rendering a passed props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass an array of users as a props to a component, when I change something and click save, the array is showed in the component but when I hit refresh, the array is disappeared, here is my code:

First in my `App.js` I'm reading an array of users from the database (works perfectly shows the list of users) :

```
const [users,setUsers] = React.useState([]);
React.useEffect( () => {
      async function fetchData() {
        await axios.get('/api/users/')
        .then(response => {
         setUsers(response.data);
      });
      }
        fetchData();
      }
    , []);
```

Then, also in `App.js`, I'm rendering a `ListComponent` that takes the users array and shows the users:

```
return (
     <ListComponent users={users} />
);
}
```

In my `ListComponent` after a page refresh the `console.log` shows an empty array `[]`

```
const ListComponent = (props) => {
React.useEffect(()=>{
      console.log(props.users); // []
},[])
```

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). (You'll need to use `setTimeout` or similar to stand in for the `fetch`.)

Comment: `ListComponent` will be called with the initial state of `users` (`[]`) at first. Later, it will be called again with whatever the fetch returned. If that isn't happening, look at why the fetch isn't working.

Comment: @Joseph - Sorry, haven't used Redux. Nothing jumped out as being wrong though... Good luck with it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you refresh the page, the `ListComponent` will be remounted, and what you are logging, is the state of the component just after it is mounted, so the user array is not already fetched. If you want log it when it is fetched, you should add the user array in the dependency array of the `useEffect` function:

```
const ListComponent = (props) => {
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(props.users); // Should be an empty array first, then updated if your fetch function is working properly
  },[props.users]);
  // ...
};
```

If you still cannot see the user array, it means that something is not happening as expected in your `fetchData` function I guess.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what was missing, thank you!

Comment: Ah, I'm glad this wasn't something else which could have been more tricky. If it solved your issue, could you please accept my answer? Thank you!

Comment: With a big pleasure!